# output correct JSON response

Tags: json, apex

I'm generating some JSON output with the following code:

```
    generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    generator.writeStartObject();
    generator.writeFieldName('employees');
    generator.writeStartArray();
    for(User u : getUsers()) {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeStringField('key', u.Id);
        generator.writeStringField('nickname', u.CommunityNickname);
        generator.writeStringField('lastname', u.LastName);
        if(u.Region__c != null) {
            generator.writeStringField('region', u.Region__c);
        }
        else {
            generator.writeStringField('region', '');
        }
        if(u.Home_District__c != null) {
            generator.writeStringField('district', u.Home_District__c);
        }
        else {
            generator.writeStringField('district', '');
        }
        if(u.Home_District__c != null) {
            generator.writeStringField('pack', u.Pack__c);
        }
        else {
            generator.writeStringField('pack', '');
        }
        generator.writeStringField('employee', u.Name);
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
    generator.writeEndArray();
    generator.writeFieldName('events');
    generator.writeStartArray();
    for(Site_Visit__c sv : getSiteVisits()) {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        if(sv.Status__c.toLowercase() == 'scheduled') {
            generator.writeFieldName('assigned');
            generator.writeStartObject();
            if(sv.Intended_Start_Date_Time__c != null) generator.writeStringField('start_date', String.valueOf(sv.Intended_Start_Date_Time__c));    
            if(sv.Estimated_Completion_Date_Time__c != null) generator.writeStringField('end_date', String.valueOf(sv.Estimated_Completion_Date_Time__c));
            generator.writeStringField('text', String.valueOf(sv.Name));
            if(sv.Assigned_Employee__c != null) generator.writeStringField('section_id', String.valueOf(sv.Assigned_Employee__c));
            generator.writeStringField('id', String.valueOf(sv.Id));
            generator.writeStringField('color', String.valueOf('#ffffff'));
            generator.writeStringField('textColor', String.valueOf('#000000'));
            generator.writeEndObject(); 
        }
        if(sv.Status__c.toLowercase() == 'unassigned') {
            generator.writeFieldName('unassigned'); 
            generator.writeStartObject();
            if(sv.Intended_Start_Date_Time__c != null) generator.writeStringField('start_date', String.valueOf(sv.Intended_Start_Date_Time__c));    
            if(sv.Estimated_Completion_Date_Time__c != null) generator.writeStringField('end_date', String.valueOf(sv.Estimated_Completion_Date_Time__c));
            generator.writeStringField('text', String.valueOf(sv.Name));
            generator.writeStringField('id', String.valueOf(sv.Id));
            generator.writeStringField('color', String.valueOf('#ffffff'));
            generator.writeStringField('textColor', String.valueOf('#000000'));
            generator.writeStringField('woNumber', String.valueOf(sv.Work_Order__r.Name));
            generator.writeStringField('woType', String.valueOf(sv.Work_Order__r.Work_Order_Type__c));
            generator.writeStringField('customer', String.valueOf(sv.Work_Order__r.Customer__c));
            generator.writeEndObject();             
        }
        generator.writeEndObject(); 
    }
    generator.writeEndArray();
    generator.writeEndObject();
```

The current output is like the following:

```
{
employees:
    employee
    employee
events:
    unassigned:
        event
    unassigned:
        event
    assigned:
        event
    assigned:
        event
    (empty object?)
    (empty object?)
}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{
employees:
    employee
    employee
events:
    unassigned:
        event
        event
    assigned:
        event
        event
}
```

Events is an object (not an array) that has two field: assigned and unassigned.  Each of those fields is an array of events that match their description.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks like Java. You should add the java tag.

Comment: @Antzi this isn't valid java code. Note the single-quoted strings. Either that or they were replaced somehow...

Comment: It isn't java, it is apex, which is a derivative of java.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your snippet I don't see why you need to use the JSON generators in apex when you could simply use the [`serialize()` method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm).

Since you're using multiple objects I would create a custom inner class and build a list of those and serialize them.

```
public MyInnerClass(User u, Site_Visit__c s){
   String userName = u.Name;
   String siteName = s.Name;
}


List<MyOuterClass.MyInnerClass> customInnerClass = new List<MyOuterClass.MyInnerClass>();

//add my inner class objects made up of properties from all my sobjects

customInnerClass.serialize(); 
//This will be a well formed JSON object for any API or JS Framework.
```